# php not getting data from Request, posting from curl

Tags: php, curl

I am firing a curl request from command line.

My curl request looks like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Content-type: application/json"  -d '{ "BookingByCustomer" : "testUser", "BookingDate" : "11111111", "TotalCost" : "11", "NetAmount"  : "11" }' http://serverIP:port/test.php
```

My PHP code:

```
    <?php
   /** global variables */
    $request_called = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') ? 'GET' : 'POST';

    if($request_called == 'POST')
    {
         handle_post_request();
    }
    if($request_called == 'GET')
     {
       handle_get_request();
     }

    function handle_get_request (){
      echo "Get Request has been called!";   
   }

    function handle_post_request (){
   $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    print_r ($_SERVER);
   }
 ?>
```

but $_SERVER doesn't seems to have json data. Did i miss something??

Comment: Hard to tell without more code. You just provided use with a function.

Comment: its faiirly simple php.. but still i post code here

Comment: I note you look for it in SERVER... shouldn't it go in POST?

Comment: You should NOT pretend you received a `POST` when you don't recognize the request method. Instead you should return a 405 HTTP error. Maybe you received a `HEAD` request...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such entry as `$_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']` in `$_SERVER`. You need to get the POST content from `$_POST`.

But as you are not giving your JSON data a variable name you should get the raw POST content with

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Another solution would be to assign a variable name to your JSON data:

```
curl -X POST ... -d 'HTTP_JSON={ ... }'
```

As long as you have no forbidden characters (like ? or &) in your JSON you are safe, otherwise you would also have to URL encode your JSON string. That's why I suggested the first solution using `php://input`. This way you don't have to care about URL encoding.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit your answer. Becasue by defination i got - "file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string." but I am not sending any file.

Comment: In php URLs are also treated as files. This one is a PHP specific URL holding the complete body of a request. You are sending your JSON in the body of a POST request so you have to get it this way. I'll also show you another way to do this using the $_POST array in a minute...

Comment: one more doubt, If i send data from andriod client, do i need to change the code? or will it work as same..

Comment: this will work for every POST request, no matter where it comes from, browser or command line, handset or desktop...

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the information with curl so use `$_POST` instead of `$_SERVER`.

```
function handle_post_request (){
    $json = $_POST['HTTP_JSON'];
    print_r ($_POST);
}
```

Comment: i tried but got a blank array ... any suggestion why it is so

Comment: $_POST is right, but as the JSON has no variable name you have to get the raw POST data

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the value of $_SERVER and not the value of the $json-variable.

```
  function handle_post_request (){
   $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    print_r ($_SERVER);
   }
```

And second I believe you have to use $_POST to get this working:

```
  function handle_post_request (){
   $json = $_POST['HTTP_JSON'];
    print_r ($json, true);
   }
```

Comment: $_POST is right, but as the JSON has no variable name you have to get the raw POST data

Comment: ahh. But then $json = $_POST['HTTP_JSON'] is totally useless?

Comment: yes because request doesn't have HTTP_JSON ..so yes it is useless until this name given to Json data.. and I was printing $_SERVER variable in first case so that i can see my all request parameter.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! :-) (No I'm not the really the best programmer in the world ;-) But I'm learning :-))